# SQL SELECT ALL BUT {array}

Tags: php, sql

I want to get all the results but the ones in the array $valuesnew.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM venue
        WHERE venue_id IN ($valuesnew)";
```

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: `$valuesnew` contain string or is numeric ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM venue
    WHERE venue_id NOT IN ('".implode("','",$valuesnew)."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * ROM venue WHERE NOT venue_id ($valuesnew)
```

[NOT Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/non-typed-operators.html) negates your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM venue
        WHERE venue_id **NOT** IN ($valuesnew)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where column NOT IN ('value1','value2','value3');
```

Comment: Values must be surrounded by quotes !

Comment: no. Strings need to be surrounded by quotes. Read more about data types

Comment: He uses the variable `$valuesnew`, so it may lead to SQL injections if you don't know what is actually in `$valuesnew`. Although it's not sufficient to secure the query...